# Seems and look + passive?

Tags: relative-clauses, to-infinitive

> 1. It looks cancelled
> 2. It looks to be cancelled
> 3. It looks like cancelled
> 4. It seems cancelled
> 5. It seems to be cancelled

I'm not sure which one is correct or how I can build sentences like that.

Answer (score 1):

Generally speaking, after "look" we use adjectives and participles (e.g. *He looks healthy*, *He looks bored*, *It looks interesting*). It means "It looks cancelled" is fine.

We can also use "like" after "look", but in this case we use a noun or a clause after "look" (e.g. *It looks like heaven*, *It looks like something is wrong*). So, don't use "cancelled" after "it looks like" because "cancelled" is a participle (but *It looks like it is cancelled* is grammatically correct).

"It looks to be" is incorrect but "it seems to be" is OK. It seems cancelled is correct too.